# Using TFS for PDF version control

Tags: version-control

I am working in a company who is using TFS'12 for keeping track of PDF versions. The problem is that they are running out of space VERY quickly. I suppose this is because TFS use SQL Server and SQL Server treats every pdf as a BLOB object.

The question is: is it possible to use TFS for doing version control on files that do not contain code (images, pdfs, videos, etc)?

Comment: I don't think it really matters whether SQL server is being used or not - if you're storing a copy of every version of a large file, you're storing a copy of every version of a large file...

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible to use TFS for this purpose. Make sure that the space situation is due to increase in data space, not log space.